# Customize contacts screen to remove some fields

Tags: contacts, summaryfields

I am looking to remove some of the fields from the main contacts form - example Nickname, source etc. etc. - I am having a tough time finding the relevant information in Civicrm documentation and the only thing I find is display preferences which doesn't give me an option to disable fields

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There was a [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/dalin/removing-fields-civicrm) sometime ago by Dalin that had a fairly in depth recipe if you want to take a look and see if that helps you make some progress. There is no option to do this through the UI - though it comes up reasonably often.

Comment: Thanks the blog post seems to have been deleted and I can't find a copy online

Comment: I don't know what you mean. that link works for me